# Automated Permission Set Group Assignment

Tags: visual-workflow

For our user provisioning (from AD) I want to automate the permission set groups that are assigned to user with a specific function title. What I have found is how to assign a permission set using the Flow Builder (create a record in the object 'Permission Set Assignment'. But I have not been able to find the same for Permission Set Groups. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both PermissionSetAssignments and PermissionSetGroups are accessible as SObjects and can be created in the database when the appropriate permissions exist. I suggest you simply need to create the PermissionSetAssignment for the User referencing the PermissionSetGroup instance. This can be done straight-forwardly in Apex using something like:

```
PermissionSetAssignment assignment = new PermissionSetAssignment(
    PermissionSetGroupId = groupId,
    AssigneeId = userId);

insert assignment;
```

Of course, you should ensure this code is bulkified if you are handling bulk provisioning, and can be accessed from a flow as long as you create an [InvocableMethod](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm) for it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I'll let you know if this worked out.